# MySQL query GROUP BY two columns

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I need help with MySQL query
I have this cenary:

**table A**
- page_id
- rev_id
- date
*one page_id can have multiples rev_id*

**table B**
- rev_id
- words
*I have what words have in each revision*

I need return for each date the quantity of words that I have in the
last rev_id in each page_id

Example:

```
table A
page_id | rev_id   |   date
---------------------------------
 1      |  231     |   2002-01-01
 2      |  345     |   2002-10-12
 1      |  324     |   2002-10-13
 3      |  348     |   2003-01-01
```

--

```
table B
rev_id | words
---------------
231    | 'ask'
231    | 'the'
231    | 'if'
345    | 'ask'
324    | 'ask'
324    | 'if'
348    | 'who'
```

**magical sql here** edited to show how its calculated {page_id : [words]}

```
date        |  count(words)
--------------------------
2002-01-01  |    3           { 1:[ask, the, if] }
2002-10-12  |    4           { 1:[ask, the, if], 2:[ask] }
2002-10-13  |    3           { 1:[ask, if], 2:[ask] }
2003-01-01  |    4           { 1:[ask, if], 2:[ask], 3:[who] }
```

I did this query, but my date are fixed and I need for all dates contained in table revision:

```
SELECT SUM(q) 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(equation) q 
    FROM revision r, equation e
    WHERE r.rev_id in (
        SELECT max(rev_id) 
        FROM revision 
        WHERE date < '2006-01-01' 
        GROUP BY page_id
    ) 
    AND r.rev_id = e.rev_id
    GROUP BY date
) q;
```

---

#### Solved

My friend help-me to create query to solve my problem!

```
select s.date, count(words) from
(select d.date, r.page_id, max(r.rev_id) as rev_id 
    from revision r, (select distinct(date) from revision) d 
    where d.date >= r.date group by d.date, r.page_id) s
join words e on e.rev_id = s.rev_id
group by s.date;
```

Comment: isn't the result of this query `SELECT  a.date, COUNT(b.words)
FROM  tableA a
  LEFT JOIN tableB b
   ON a.rev_id = b.rev_id
GROUP BY a.date` you wanted to achieve? this will display the date even without revisiosn.

Comment: I can't figure out how the numbers in your example add up.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I put one example how SUM the numbers

Comment: @JohnWoo No, your query takes all previous revision from each date, i need just last rev_id for each page_id

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a basic `join` and `group by`:

```
select a.date, count(*)
from a join
     b
     on a.rev_id = b.rev_id
group by a.date;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I think I get it.  This is a cumulative thing.  That makes it more complicated.

```
select d.date,
       (select count(*)
        from a join
             b
             on a.rev_id = b.rev_id
        where a.date <= d.date and
              a.rev_id = (select max(a2.rev_id) from a a2 where a2.date = a.date and a2.date <= d.date)
       ) as cnt
from (select date from a) d;
```

But that won't work in MySQL because of the nesting of the correlation clause.  So, we can restructure the logic as:

```
select a.date, count(*)
from (select a.*,
             (select max(a2.rev_id)
              from a a2
              where a2.date <= a.date and a2.page_id = a.page_id
             ) as last_rev_id
      from a
     ) a join
     b
     on a.last_rev_id = b.rev_id
group by a.date;
```

Comment: it's doesn't work properly... With your query in 2005-02-16, it's got 399, but the correct sum is 270.

Comment: Yes, i need sleep now, tomorrow, ill test again, thanks